# JQuery to Parse XML file in Electron

Tags: jquery, xml, get, electron

I have the following XML file:

test.xml

```
<Page>
<Checkbox>
    <label>Works</label>
</Checkbox>
</Page>
```

I have Electron set up and have JQuery implemented correctly. When I say:

```
var xml = "<Page><Checkbox><label>Works</label></Checkbox></Page>";
var doc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(doc);
var $checkbox = $xml.find("Checkbox");
$checkbox.each(function(){
    var label = $(this).find('label').text();
    $(".ntbk-container" ).append('<input type=checkbox class=checkbox>'+label+"</input>");
});
```

The page renders correctly and I get a checkbox. However I want it to read from a File, so I did what I've seen many people do:

```
var file
$.get(file_path,function(data){
    file = data;
},'text')
var xml = file;
...(The rest of the prevoious Code)
```

Then I get no Result. How will I be able to do this?

Comment: You have to consume the data inside the `$.get()` callback. AJAX is asynchronous. You are trying to process it before it has even been returned

Comment: Just a suggestion, If I were you I would use the node package 'xml2js' and deal with all the downloading and parsing taking advantage of the node powered browser Electron is. You could also manage the downloading of the file using then node 'http' library.